# What is the quadratic covariation $[|B|,B](t)$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

What is the quadratic covariation $[|B|,B](t)$? I know if the absolute value isn't there, the quadratic variation is just $t$. I also know Tanaka formula. But I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Perhaps start by writing Tanaka's formula.

Comment: @user6247850 Then what?

Comment: Well, do that first and add it to the question.  Then think about how you could compute the quadratic covariation of it with $B_t$.